# Power BI - Desktop DateTime From Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, powerbi-desktop

I'm using an Azure Cosmos DB that is populated through the Azure Cosmos .NET SDK. According to the documentation, DateTimes should be stored as a serialized string in ISO_8601 format (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/working-with-dates). When I view my records in the azure portal or the azure storage explorer app, it appears like that is the case.

[image]

You can see my StartTime and EndTime properties as well as the TimeStamp are in the format "2019-07-15T16:24:51.392Z"

When I import the data to Power BI Desktop, the value comes out as some bizarre string/number. e.g.

00636988010188048801

I thought that perhaps it was the # of milliseconds since 1/1/1970, but that is not the case. Does anyone know how to get the date time imported into Power BI correctly or how to convert that value to a datetime? Trying to just set the data type to any of the various DateTime options results in an error.

The advanced editor looks like the following:

```
let
    Source = DocumentDB.Contents("https://myurl.documents.azure.com:443/"),
    TablesDB = Source{[id="TablesDB"]}[Collections],
    TablesDB_InstanceData = TablesDB{[db_id="TablesDB",id="InstanceData"]}[Documents],
    #"Expanded Document" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(TablesDB_InstanceData, "Document", {"id", "RunId", "InstanceId", "StartTime", "EndTime", "MessagesProcessed", "IsCompareInstance", "_ts"}, {"id", "RunId", "InstanceId", "StartTime", "EndTime", "MessagesProcessed", "IsCompareInstance", "_ts"}),
    #"Expanded RunId" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Document", "RunId", {"$v"}, {"$v"}),
    #"Expanded InstanceId" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded RunId", "InstanceId", {"$v"}, {"$v.1"}),
    #"Expanded StartTime" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded InstanceId", "StartTime", {"$v"}, {"$v.2"}),
    #"Expanded EndTime" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded StartTime", "EndTime", {"$v"}, {"$v.3"}),
    #"Expanded MessagesProcessed" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded EndTime", "MessagesProcessed", {"$v"}, {"$v.4"}),
    #"Expanded IsCompareInstance" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded MessagesProcessed", "IsCompareInstance", {"$v"}, {"$v.5"})
in
    #"Expanded IsCompareInstance"
```

Comment: Can you share the Power Query code and any DAX that interacts with these timestamps? A quick test with `DateTime.From("2019-07-15T16:24:51.392Z")` interprets the string as a datetime with no issues.

Comment: I'm very new to power bi, I'm not sure what the power query code or DAX is? I put the code that is from the "Advanced Editor" in the question. It's not clear to me how exactly the data is stored. I don't know for sure if the Azure Data Explorer is transforming the data to show it as a date or what, but power bi does not show it in the date form, it shows as that weird number.

Comment: As a follow up, I submitted an issue to the Azure Cosmos Table SDK github page where they said they are storing the date in some format that they aren't releasing. So that is why I can't figure it out. https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-table-dotnet/issues/14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I posted this as an issue to the Power BI community, someone there posted the way to handle this:

```
let

ConvertTimestamp = (ts) => #datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) + #duration(0, 0, 0, ts / 10000000)

in

ConvertTimestamp(635912639960000000)
```